# Business days between two columns of dates with Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have a `Dataframe` in `Pandas` with a letter and two dates as columns. I would like to calculate the difference between the two date columns for the previous row using `shift(1)` provided that the `Letter`value is the same (using a `groupby`). The complex part is I would like to calculate business days, not just elapsed days. The best way I have found to do that is using a `numpy.busday_count`, which takes two lists as an argument. I am essentially trying to use `.apply` to make each row it's own list. Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but running into some problems, which are ambiguous.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', datetime(2016,01,07), datetime(2016,01,09)],
                        ['A', datetime(2016,03,01), datetime(2016,03,8)],
                        ['B', datetime(2016,05,01), datetime(2016,05,10)],
                        ['B', datetime(2016,06,05), datetime(2016,06,07)]],
                   columns=['Letter', 'First Day', 'Last Day'])

# convert to dates since pandas reads them in as time series
df['First Day'] = df['First Day'].apply(lambda x: x.to_datetime().date())
df['Last Day'] = df['Last Day'].apply(lambda x: x.to_datetime().date())

df['Gap'] = (df.groupby('Letter')
                         .apply(
                                lambda x: (
                                            np.busday_count(x['First Day'].shift(1).tolist(),
                                                            x['Last Day'].shift(1).tolist())))
                         .reset_index(drop=True))
print df
```

I get the following error on the `lambda` function. I'm not sure what object it's having problems with as the two passed arguments should be dates:

```
ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime
```

Desired Output:

```
  Letter   First Day    Last Day   Gap
0      A  2016-01-07  2016-01-09  NAN
1      A  2016-03-01  2016-03-08  1
2      B  2016-05-01  2016-05-10  NAN
3      B  2016-06-05  2016-06-07  7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work - first removing the leading zeros from the date digits):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', datetime(2016, 1, 7), datetime(2016, 1, 9)],
                        ['A', datetime(2016, 3, 1), datetime(2016, 3, 8)],
                        ['B', datetime(2016, 5, 1), datetime(2016, 5, 10)],
                        ['B', datetime(2016, 6, 5), datetime(2016, 6, 7)]],
                  columns=['Letter', 'First Day', 'Last Day'])

df['Gap'] = df.groupby('Letter')
              .apply(
               lambda x: 
                   pd.DataFrame(
                       np.busday_count(x['First Day'].tolist(), x['Last Day'].tolist())).shift())
                  .reset_index(drop=True)

  Letter  First Day   Last Day  Gap
0      A 2016-01-07 2016-01-09  NaN
1      A 2016-03-01 2016-03-08  2.0
2      B 2016-05-01 2016-05-10  NaN
3      B 2016-06-05 2016-06-07  6.0
```

I don't think you need the `.date()` conversion.

Comment: this yields `TypeError: Cannot cast datetime.datetime object from metadata [us] to [D] according to the rule 'same_kind'` Note. I also remove the `.date()` conversion as you mentioned. Could you post a full solution?

Comment: I changed the `datetime` definitions in your sample because the leading zeros didn't work. The error suggests something's awry with the date formats? What's your input format?

Comment: input format is exactly as I typed it, except I took your suggestion and removed the leading 0s. Still get the same issue.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you copy and run the above code?

Comment: The error message is because datetime uses micro-seconds [us] as idefault, but NumPy uses days [D]. Suggestions are to specify the dtype using [us] or some form of seconds units, e.g.: [s], [ms]. Alternatively, use the `.date()` conversion again to get rid of the `us`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113561/discussion-between-user2242044-and-stefan).